# "qemu-system-riscv: command not found"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qemu, riscv

While trying to install QEMU as instructed at http://riscv.org/getting-started.html#qemu, the **"qemu-system-riscv: command not found"**error shows up when the following command is run:
        qemu-system-riscv -hda [Location of root.bin] -kernel [Location of vmlinux] -nographic

I checked the riscv-softmmu direcory and qemu-system-riscv is there in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in correct if you haven't added the risc-sofftmmu directory to path

Also try using ./qemu-system-riscv if you haven't added the folder to the path

Answer (score 0):

The Qemu binary is available in the directory configured during the build. Following are standard steps followed.

```
  mkdir build
  cd build
  ../configure
  make
```

If standard steps as above are followed the binary is in *build/riscv64-softmmu/*